# Determine touch/click of 4 Polygons from a Rectangle using libgdx

Tags: java, geometry, libgdx

I'm currently working with `libgdx`, and am trying to get 4 equal `Polygons` from a `Rectangle`:

```
Rectangle myRect = Rectangle(0, 0, 171, 171);
```

I am looking to determine the 4 `Polygons` that represent each side of the `Rectangle`[image]

This is my first day working with this engine, and I am a bit rusty on my geometry, so I'm looking for any help I can get. Essentialy, I'm going to use these `Polygons` to determine whether a specified X,Y pair is within them.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the mid point of the rectangle fairly easily, just average the height and width.  From there you could manually construct a polygon, jumping from corner to corner to midpoint.  You would lose some precision due to rounding, but you can use `getX()` and `getWidth()` if you need double precision.

```
public Polygon[] findTris(Rectangle rectangle){
    //Creating a list of the x points of the rectangle, ordered clockwise.
    new int[] xpoints = new int[5];
    xpoints[0] = rectangle.x;
    xpoints[1] = rectangle.x+rectangle.width;
    xpoints[2] = rectangle.x+rectangle.width;
    xpoints[3] = rectangle.x;
    xpoints[4] = rectangle.x;

    //Doing the same for y points.
    int[] ypoints = new int[5];
    ypoints[0] = rectangle.y;
    ypoints[1] = rectangle.y;
    ypoints[2] = rectangle.y+rectangle.height;
    ypoints[3] = rectangle.y+rectangle.height;
    ypoints[4] = rectangle.y;

    //Finding the midpoint.
    int midx = (rectangle.x+rectangle.width)/2;
    int midy = (rectangle.y+rectangle.height)/2;

    //Creating an array to hold the polygons.
    Polygon[] polys = new Polygon[4];

    //Creating the polygons.
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int[] triXPoints = {xpoints[i], xpoints[i+1], midx};
        int[] triYPoints = {ypoints[i], ypoints[i+1], midy};
        polys[i] = Polygon(xpoints,ypoints,3);
    }
    return polys;
}
```

Now that will work fine, but if all you are trying to do is find the mouse position in a square, you can use mouse maps.  A mouse map is an image with distinctly different colors in each region that you want to be able to recognize the mouse in.  You would store the map as a `BufferedImage` and whenever you needed to find the region the mouse was in, you can get the color of the buffered image at the appropriate position on the `BufferedImage`.
Here is the idea:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFPsl.png

Comment: Yes, what I am trying to do is determine which triangle of the square is pressed. I am using a Sprite. I will look into your approach above, and also look into a MouseMap (does this work with touch also?. Also, by looking at your code, the for loop at the end will get an out of bounds exception because of i + 1

Comment: A map will work for any ordered pair. And yeah, I missed the out of bounds, it's fixed.